# how to get (3623752876 * 3623752876) % 4294434817 in c

Tags: c, long-integer

I implemented a fast-power algorithm to perform the operation `(x^y) % m`.

Since `m` is very large (`4294434817`), I used `long long` to store the result. However, `long long` still seems not enough during the operation. For example, I got a negative number for `(3623752876 * 3623752876) % 4294434817`.

Is there anyway to figure it out?

Comment: Use `uint64_t` because although `uint32_t` is large enough to hold the operand, it won't hold the product.

Comment: What do you mean with "figure out"? If `long long` is too small? use a calculator and check if the result is > `LLONG_MAX`. If you mean if there is a larger standard integer type which has more than 64 bits? No! Use a big-integer (i.e. one with "unlimited" integers) library. Note to ensure all calculations are done as `long long`, resp. `unsigned long long` to double positive range.

Comment: @KingstonChan will you please clarify *in your question* whether the calculation is `(x * y) % m` or `(x ^ y) % m` or `pow(x, y) % m`?

Comment: `3623752876ULL * 3623752876 % 4294434817`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three of those constants are between 2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>32</sup>.

The type `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be able to store values up to at least 2<sup>64</sup>-1, which exceeds the product `3623752876 * 3623752876`.

So just use `unsigned long long` for the calculation. `long long` is wide enough to hold the individual constants, but not the product.

You could also use `uint64_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>`. Unlike `unsigned long long`, it's guaranteed to be *exactly* 64 bits wide. Since you don't really need an exact width of 64 bits (128-bit arithmetic would work just as well), `uint_least64_t` or `uint_fast64_t` is probably more suitable. But `unsigned long long` is arguably simpler, and in this case it will work correctly. (`uint64_t` is not guaranteed to exist, though on any C99 or later implementation it almost certainly will.)

For larger values, including intermediate results, you'll likely need to use something wider than `unsigned long long`, which is likely to require some kind of multi-precision arithmetic.  The GNU [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library is one possibility. Another is to use a language that has built-in support for arbitrary-width integer arithmetic (such as Python).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the calculation `(x * x) % y` although the question is not entirely clear.

Use `uint64_t` because although `unsigned int` is large enough to hold the operands, and the result, it won't hold the product.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned x = 3623752876;
    unsigned m = 4294434817;
    uint64_t r;

    r = ((uint64_t)x * x) % m;
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned)r);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
3896043471
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the power of modulus arithmetic to do such calculations. The fundamental property of multiplication in modulus arithmetic for two numbers a and b states:

> `(a*b)%m = ((a%m)*(b%m))%m`

If m fits into the long long int type, then the above calculation will never overflow.
Since you are trying to do modular exponentiation, you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).